# Post Form initiates Get Request

Tags: php, html, post, get

I have created a form that initiates a POST request upon clicking the submit button. However, eventually, I realized that the PHP code that handles the requests is not functioning correctly. When I tried to debug the code, I opened up the network tab and tested by submiting the form. Instead of initiating a POST request, a GET request shows up on my network, which explains why the PHP code is not functioning correctly, because it actually never receives a POST request. However, I cannot understand why there may be a GET request instead of a POST. Does anyone have any ideas?

**Update**: Does this have anything to do with the redirect property of my .htaccess file?

**.htaccess file**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>


    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

**Picture of Console Tab after submitting form.** Even though my network registers a POST request, my console always prints out "GET REQUEST", which means that my PHP method register only receives a GET request, despite what my network says.

[image: Picture of Network Tab after submitting form. Why is there a GET request instead of a POST upon submitting the form?]

**HTML Code** (my Form):

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">

                        <fieldset>
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-top">

                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <h3>Insight Contributor Account Info</h3>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-top-right">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-bottom" style="height: 400px">
                                <!--Name-->
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                                        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                               placeholder="Full Name (e.g. John Doe)" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                                        <br>

                                        @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                            <h3> name is required</h3>
                                        </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--Email-->
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email"
                                               placeholder="Primary Email Address (e.g.Jdoe@gmail.com)"
                                               value="{{ old('email') }}"><br>
                                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--Password-->
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <!-- <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>-->
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control"
                                               placeholder="Password (at least 6 character)" name="password"><br>
                                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--PasswordConfirm-->
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control"
                                               placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password_confirmation"><br>

                                        @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                                <h3> password mismatch</h3>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-top" style="margin-top: 10px">

                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <h3>Professional Information</h3>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-bottom" style="height: 460px">
                                <!--Primary Industry(single value)-->
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('industry') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><br>
                                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="industry" id="industry">
                                            <option selected disabled>Primary Industry</option>
                                            <option>Art</option>
                                            <option>Business</option>
                                            <option>Law</option>
                                            <option>Media</option>
                                            <option>Medicine</option>
                                            <option>Education</option>
                                            <option>Technology</option>
                                            <option> Science</option>
                                            <option>Service</option>
                                            <option>Other</option>
                                        </select>


                                        @if ($errors->has('industry'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('industry') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <!--Primary Job Function (single value)-->
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('job_function') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><br>
                                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="job_function"
                                                id="job_function">
                                            <option selected disabled>Primary Job Function</option>
                                            @foreach($professions as $profession)
                                                <option @if ($profession->id == old('job_function_id')) selected
                                                        @endif value="{{ $profession->id }}">{{ $profession->name }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>

                                        @if ($errors->has('job_function'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('job_function') }}</strong>
                                            </span>@endif



                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!--Add relative experience (multi tag)-->
                                <div id="tags" class="form-group" style="margin-top: 30px">

                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><br>


                                        <select id="test" style="width: 100%;margin-left: 10%;" name="tags[]"
                                                multiple>

                                            <option value="root" disabled="disabled">Tags</option>
                                            <option value="level11" parent="root" disabled="disabled">Subjects
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="level12" parent="root" disabled="disabled">Grades
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="level13" parent="root" disabled="disabled">Relationship
                                                Management
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="level14" parent="root" disabled="disabled">Classroom
                                                Management & Design
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="level15" parent="root" disabled="disabled">Curricula &
                                                Resources
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="level16" parent="root" disabled="disabled">Professional
                                                Growth & Career Management
                                            </option>
                                            <option value="level17" parent="root" disabled="disabled">More</option>
                                            @foreach($tags as $tag)

                                                @if($tag->category =='Subjects')
                                                    <option value='{{ $tag->id }}'
                                                            parent="level11"> {{$tag->name}}</option>
                                                @endif
                                                @if($tag->category =='Grades')
                                                    <option value='{{ $tag->id }}'
                                                            parent="level12"> {{$tag->name}}</option>
                                                @endif
                                                @if($tag->category =='Relationship Management')
                                                    <option value='{{ $tag->id }}'
                                                            parent="level13"> {{$tag->name}}</option>
                                                @endif
                                                @if($tag->category =='Classroom Management & Design')
                                                    <option value='{{ $tag->id }}'
                                                            parent="level14"> {{$tag->name}}</option>
                                                @endif
                                                @if($tag->category =='Curricula & Resources')
                                                    <option value='{{ $tag->id }}'
                                                            parent="level15"> {{$tag->name}}</option>
                                                @endif
                                                @if($tag->category =='Professional Growth & Career Management')
                                                    <option value='{{ $tag->id }}'
                                                            parent="level16"> {{$tag->name}}</option>
                                                @endif
                                                @if($tag->category =='More')
                                                    <option value='{{ $tag->id }}'
                                                            parent="level17"> {{$tag->name}}</option>
                                                @endif
                                            @endforeach

                                        </select>
                                        @if ($errors->has('tags'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('tags') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <!--Bio-->
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('bio') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <!--  <label for="bio" class="col-md-4 control-label">Short Bio</label> -->

                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><br>
                                    <textarea id="bio" class="form-control" placeholder="Brief profile bio"
                                              name="bio">{{ old(nl2br('bio')) }}</textarea><br>


                                        @if ($errors->has('bio'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('bio') }}</strong>

                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-top" style="margin-top: 10px">

                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <h3> Agreements </h3>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-top-right">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-bottom">

                                <!--Terms-->
                                <h2 class="section-heading">Cypress Community Principles</h2>
                                <p class="lead">
                                    <br>
                                    Teachers value each other for their expertise.<br><br>

                                    Teachers believe in the power of collaboration and will work together to engage
                                    in
                                    open and honest dialogue, provide guidance and mentorship, and create content
                                    that
                                    supports growth and success for fellow teachers.<br><br>

                                    Teachers will respect each other and be mindful of what they post. We encourage,
                                    open and honest communication, a diversity of perspectives, and thoughtful
                                    disagreement. Harassment, disrespect, and inappropriate content are not
                                    tolerated.<br><br>

                                    Teachers will actively engage in fostering a positive community of learning and
                                    growth.<br><br>

                                    Teachers are the most significant influence on a student’s academic achievement
                                    and
                                    will support fellow teachers as agents of change and innovators of
                                    education.<br><br>
                                </p>

                                <form action="#"
                                      onsubmit="
                                  if(document.getElementById('agree').checked) {
                                  return true;

                                  } else
                                  { alert('Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy');
                                  return false;
                                  }">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value=0 id="agree"/> I have read and
                                    agree to
                                    the Community Principle,
                                    <a href="/terms" style="color: #5dc19f">Terms
                                        and Conditions
                                    </a> and
                                    <a href="/privacypolicy" style="color: #5dc19f">Privacy
                                        Policy</a><br><br>

                                </form>

                                <!--Signup botton-->
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default"
                                        style="background-color: #a5d5a7">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i> Sign me up!
                                </button>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #a5d5a7">
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/') }}" style="color: whitesmoke">
                                        Cancel </a>
                                </button>


                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                    </form>
```

**PHP Code** (I utilized console to check what type of request is reaching the PHP Code):

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        echo '<script>console.log("request()");</script>';
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $professions = Profession::all();
        if($request->isMethod('get')){
            echo '<script>console.log("GET REQUEST");</script>';
        }
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            echo '<script>console.log("POST REQUEST");</script>';
            $validator = $this->validateRegister($request->input());
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            }

            $user = Iuser::create([
                'name' => $request['name'],
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),
                'bio' => $request['bio'],
                'industry' => $request['industry'],
                'confirmation_code' => str_random(30),
                'job_function' => $request['job_function'],
            ]);
            $user ->tags()->sync($request['tags']);

            #event(new NewUserWasRegistered($user));


            if($user->save()){
                return redirect('/insight/login')->with('success', 'Welcome to Cypress！');
            }else{
                return back()->with('error', 'Register failed！')->withInput();
            }
        }
        $datas = array('tags' => $tags, 'professions'=>$professions);
        #return $user;
        return view('iauth.register')->with($datas);
    }



    protected function validateRegister(array $data)
    {
        echo '<script>console.log("validateRegister");</script>';
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6',
            'bio' => 'required',
            'industry' => 'required|string',
            'job_function' => 'required|string',
        ], [
            'required' => ':attribute is required',

            'min' => ':attribute is too short',
            'confirmed' => 'different passwords',
            'unique' => 'This email exits',
            'max' => ':attribute is too long'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Be sure you have "preserve log" checked in the network console. It looks like it is using PRG.

Comment: You can not nest `form` elements in HTML, you need to fix that first of all.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but I think you may not be saving request logs in your browser developer tools network tab.

Your controller is using the [Post-Redirect-Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) method. After it processes the request, it returns a response using either `redirect()` or `back()` (also a redirect).

So there *is* a POST request, but if you don't persist the request logs in the browser tools, the subsequent GET request will replace it in the network tab. Look for a setting called "Persist Logs" in Firefox, or "Preserve log" in Chrome. (Sorry, I'm not sure what it's called in IE/Edge, I can't get to it right now, but I assume it has something like that too.)

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the Post-Redirect-Get method, which has definetly helped. However, my main problem(which I definetly did not explain clearly) is that even though the POST request shows up on my network tab, my console continues to print out "GET REQUEST", which means that my PHP method register() only receives the GET request (despite the fact that the network shows a POST request)

Comment: Oops, well, I guess this answer is not so useful then. I'll take another look tomorrow.